# Google Apps DKIM Start Authentication fails even though DKIM TXT Record is Available

Tags: dkim

I am using Google Apps for my domain jkltech.in, I wanted to sign my e-mails with DKIM Keys as I am using Google App Engine for my website.

I have registered my TXT Record with my DNS provider, but I am unable to start authentication in my Google Apps Account. I am using Google Apps for Free. I have verfied my DNS entry using various tools such as dig and other online tools, http://www.protodave.com/security/checking-your-dkim-dns-record/

Do let me know what I am missing, is my TXT record wrong or is there some other issue with my configuration,

Regards,
Jay

Answer (score 3):

this is apparently a known issue and they're still working on a fix. See the Google Product Forum thread at https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/apps/FOsrXULt66Y/discussion. Cheers.